# What is this open panel at the rear of this airplane?

Tags: boeing, apu, tail

I saw this photo at [another interesting question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/17676/why-cant-horizontal-stabilizers-be-longer-than-they-are-today?rq=1):

[image]

There's an open square panel. What is it?

P.S. Any tag suggestions are welcome. All I could think of was "tail".

EDIT: are there any other tags for this kind of thing? The APU tag seems to be a crystal ball because I had no idea what it was at the time.

Comment: I'm guessing it's APU related.

Comment: [Next question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/24427/8730)

Answer (score 33):

It is the [Auxiliary Power Unit (APU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_power_unit) inlet door.

[image: APU inlet]

Image from [Boeing Aero Magazine](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/articles/2010_q4/3/)

Comment: Next question: why is does the inlet face upwards, where rain can get in? If it opened downwards, they wouldn't have to put a door on it at all.

Comment: @steveverrill I don't think the door is for rain protection but for aerodynamics. Afaik the APU is not used in-flight. So you can cover the inlet with a door because a "hole" in the fuselage would generate drag.

Comment: it if were facing down, it would be subject to FOD. it probably has an inertial separator not just for rain, but for debris as well.

Comment: oh and here i thought the question was asking about the square open panel below the tail number and door... @DrZ214

Comment: @steveverrill Rain isn't usually a problem for jet engines. FOD is, though

Comment: @TomMcW Sure I missed the possibility of FOD, but the reason rain isn't usually a problem for jet engines is because they're normally horizontal and have a fairly straight flow path. Undrained water collected in intake of any type of engine while stopped can potentially cause damage on startup, as well as corrosion while shut down. If door was damaged, and there was significant rain while APU was stopped, I'd want to check it before flying on it. It's possible there's a drain line to prevent water collecting in the intake, but I cant see it in the drawing, nor can I see an opening in the photo

Comment: @steveverrill Yeah, it's prob not advisable to let water sit in there while it's not running. I'm assuming the door is normally only open when the apu is in use. So preventing rain ingress may be one reason the door is there. The diagram does show a drain for the exhaust, though. I guess because it can't be closed.

Comment: @Michael oops, i ddnt even notice that tiny one on the underside. I thought the one with the blue stripe was the only open panel in the photo.