# What is this device protruding from the rear of this 787?

Tags: feature-identification, apu, sensors

While looking at the photos from [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24413/what-is-this-open-panel-at-the-rear-of-this-airplane)
I noticed a small protrusion from the side of the plane. You can see it in the photo:
[image: 787 photo]

and in the diagram from l@aeroalias answer:

[image: 787 apu diagram]

In the diagram it appears to have something to do with the apu or is fire protection system. There's a shaded line running to it.

What is this object?

---

Edit: It does look like an antenna. I found a diagram of 777 antenna placement [here](http://www.avsim.com/topic/451568-glideslope-callout/), but it doesn't show anything in that area.

[image: 777 antenna placement]

Comment: Some of those lines don't seem to point to what they're labeled. `APU Compartment Firewall`, `Inlet Door`, etc.

Comment: @egid Yeah. Aeroalias noted that on the other question.

Comment: Since its possibly part of the fire suppression system, maybe an air intake for the [AFFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefighting_foam) system, although I don't know why it would be shaped like that, maybe because of the boundary layer problem in flight wouldn't allow it to suck in enough air to generate foam...

Comment: It looks an awful lot like a standard blade antenna, maybe for TCAS? Not sure if it has a twin on the other side.

Comment: @mins Thanks. Fixed it

Comment: @mins huh. Interesting.

Comment: A drain port for the APU?

Comment: I agree it looks like a VHF or similar antenna too, though I haven't been able to find a diagram of antenna placements for the 787.

Comment: Yes, looks like a drain mast to me.

Comment: @Porcupine911 Hadn't thought of that.  Good suggestion, except I've found several sites that indicate that the 787 doesn't have a drain mast. They opted for a grey water tank instead.

Comment: @TomMcW, I was thinking of a drain from something else. The 787 still has drains to remove any pooled fuel, oil, water, de-ice fluid, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you have already imagined, it's the APU fuel line shroud drain, as visible here:

[image]
<sup>([Source](https://www.flickr.com/photos/21746387@N06/14516248098))</sup>

Detail:

[image]

The fin gives an aerodynamic profile to the drain. The reason this drain exists seems to be:

> Natural fuel leaks from the auxiliary power unit (APU) fueling line
>   were supposed to drain harmlessly out the bottom of the structure as
>   designed, though rather than do that, the fuel was pooling into the
>   APU exhaust cone.

<sup>([Source](http://www.think-dash.com/2011/06/apu-drainage-behind-boeings-787-tail.html))</sup>

Comment: Seems to be a lot of drag causing surface area for a drain line. I'm surprised that the fin extends so far from the surface and is so "deep" (fore to aft).

Comment: @FreeMan If the drain is too close to the surface, leaked fuel and oil will flow along the fuselage with the airflow, eventually reaching the hot exhaust and ignite.

Comment: @user71659 ah, that makes sense!

Comment: What do they mean by "natural fuel leaks"?

Comment: @user71659, Indeed.  If the fuel leakage took place within the boundary layer, it would "fall" back and stick to the fuselage, hence the need for such lengthy fin.