# What are these four little things between the horizontal and vertical stabilizer on the B737?

Tags: aircraft-design, boeing-737

I was looking at some photos today and came across this one:

[image]
<sub>Image [source](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Indonesia---Air/Boeing-737-2X9-Adv-Surveiller/1919586/L/&sid=28b379ca97685d0b23e985a0b3a9fcb0)</sub>

I noticed four little things in between the horizontal and vertical stabilizer. Could somebody explain me what those are?

Comment: From what I see, they are not antennae. I might guess that they are static-relievers but I may be wrong.

Comment: We also have this question which is very similar http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24427/what-is-this-device-protruding-from-the-rear-of-this-787

Comment: do you mean the metal plates over the fuselage?

Comment: Personally, looking at that picture I would asked about tube like formation on the back.

Comment: What are those "tube-like" structures ahead of the vortex generators ?

Comment: @JorgeAldo I would say that they are side-looking radar antennas. (this aircraft is part of the indonesian air force, probably a patroller/airborne radar station).

Answer (score 21):

The objects are [vortex generators](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13876/1696). In general, vortex generators serve to introduce turbulence which helps to prevent flow separation. More information [here](http://www.b737.org.uk/fuselage.htm#AFT_BODY_VORTEX_GENERATORS):

> This was to reduce elevator and elevator tab vibration during flight to increase their hinge bearing service life.

As mentioned on the site, you can see these on any 737 version from the original -100/-200 up through the NG. Better image from same site:

[image: View of aft body vortex generators]