# What are those in the belly of a 747?

Tags: boeing-747

In the next picture what are the items circled in red?

[image: 747 undercarriage]
[Photographed by Adrian Pingstone in August 2002 and released to the public domain.](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Undercarriage.b747.arp.jpg)

Comment: related, if not duplicate: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/16566/1467

Comment: [This is what is on the other side](http://i.stack.imgur.com/670Mv.png). Additional details: [Why is air mixed with bypass air on the A/C of an aircraft?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24809/why-is-air-mixed-with-bypass-air-on-the-a-c-of-an-aircraft/24820#24820)

Answer (score 11):

The forward ones are a ram air inlet (NACA duct) for the Environmental conditioning System (ECS) and what looks like an antenna. The aft one is an exit louver for the ECS.

Comment: @Federico You're right. I didn't see that :). Looks like an antenna.

Comment: I don't think it's an antenna, I think it's a drain, similar to [here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/24427/1696).

Answer (score 4):

The forward inlets are air inlets for the air conditioning and pressurisation.
I am not sure of the after ringed area.